# IONIC - Grid Responsiva

Tags: ionic, grid, layout-responsivo

Boa tarde,

Tenho a seguinte GRID com IONIC, está desta forma:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="cell-2">
      <ion-col>
        Código
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        Nome
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        Tipo
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        Descricao
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dados" class="cell-1">
      <ion-col>
        {{item.CODIGO}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        {{item.NOME}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        {{item.TIPO}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        {{item.DESCRICAO}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Porém, na hora de visualizar ela no celular ela fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu CSS está assim:

```
page-cadastrar-ferramenta {

      .cell-1 {
        background-color: #C5DCFC;

      }

      .cell-2 {
        background-color: #262B69;
        color: white;
      }
}
```

Podem me ajudar a deixar a GRID responsiva para dispositivos celulares?

A minha ação que retorna os dados é a seguinte:

```
 listar(){

    let data = {
      "token" : ""
  };

    this.http.get('http://www.ferramentasapi.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/ferramentas', data, {})
    .then(data => {

      console.log(JSON.parse(data.data).rows); // data received by server
      this.dados = JSON.parse(data.data).rows;

    })
    .catch(error => {


    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que queres as colunas todas com o mesmo tamanho, o html deve ter o seguinte formato:

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-3>
    Código
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    Nome
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    Tipo
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    Descricao
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of dados">
  <ion-col col-3>
    {{item.CODIGO}}
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    {{item.NOME}}
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    {{item.TIPO}}
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-3>
    {{item.DESCRICAO}}
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

o 'ion-row' ocupa sempre 100% da largura disponível. O tratamento do tamanho deve ser dados nas colunas. O este sistema de grid funciona em 12 colunas, novo vamos querer 4 colunas de 3, o que dá 12.